# How to run/simulate sample code after building code with MPLAB on proteus?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, proteus

How do i simulate the PIC controller after compiling code in MPLAB?
COde is :-

```
#include "16F877A.h"

void main()

      {

           output_D(255);

                      }
```

When i add this file to PIC in proteus i got this as an error:

- "EXTERNAL MODEL DLL "PIC16DLL" NOT FOUND
- SIMULATION FAILED DUE TO FATAL SIMULATOR ERRORS

[image]

Comment: How about pasting the messages as text instead of an oversized screenshot, so people may actually read them, you actually might get an answer and others can find the question when they Google for it?

Comment: I've done that please have a look

Comment: Re-install your proteus software.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have the files that are used to simulate the various mcu's installed correctly.  either the files aren't included with your installation, they are in a seperate file, or just pay attention to install options and reinstall.